# Is it possible to configure nginx proxy_pass to retry several times if backend is temporarily down?

Tags: nginx

I have the following `nginx.conf` file:

```
events { }
daemon off;
error_log /dev/stdout info;
http {  
    access_log /dev/stdout;
    server {
        listen 80;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://backend:3000;
        }
    }        
}
```

Is it possible to configure nginx's `proxy_pass` to retry several times if backend is temporarily down?

I found that nginx has a `max_fails` parameter but it's intended to use as a healthcheck until a node is removed from the recognized backends. I have only one backend but that can be occasionally down due to container restarts.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out by any chance?

Comment: Unfortunately no :( It seems there isn't a good solution for that in nginx :(